# Add a space infront of an output that is in a loop

Tags: python

I want to add a spacing infront of the question marks. But its in a loop, adding end=" " will just add more spacing between the question marks. I am curious if there is another method of doing it other than this without importing sys but instead use the print() method:

```
import sys

def display_board(board):
    for rows in board:
        sys.stdout.write(" "* 20)
        for columns in rows:
            # Display "?" for hidden cells and the actual letter for visible cells
            sys.stdout.write(("?" if columns != "@" else "@"))
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Output:

```
                    ?????????
                    ?????????
                    ?????????
                    ?????????
                    ?????????
                    ?????????
                    ?????????
                    ?????????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly use `print()` to do this:

```
def display_board(board):
    pad = " " * 20
    for row in board:
        line = pad + "".join('?' if column != '@' else '@' for column in row)
        print(line)
```

This works by iterating over each row in the board, then doing a list comprehension over each item in each row, joining the results together into a single string and then padding it with whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `sys.stdout.write` with print, and to avoid adding a new line when printing, include `end=''`.

```py
def display_board(board):
    for rows in board:
        print(" " * 20, end="")
        for columns in rows:
            # Display "?" for hidden cells and the actual letter for visible cells
            print("?" if columns != "@" else "@", end="")
        print() // Prints newline
```